# What is the difference between these tests ? unit testing React JS - jest / enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

Unable to run the following test:

file2.test.js both methods are listed but i am trying to test the deleteAxisByid method . The first method I already have a test case for it

```
 addNewAxis = (obj) => {
let localState = Object.assign({}, this.state)
localState.axis[obj.id] = obj
let updateObj = {
  0: {
    pipe: 'chart',
    action: 'transform',
    transformType: 'replaceElement',
    matchValue: 'axes',
    axes: localState.axis
  }
}
this.props.addAxisList(updateObj)
this.setState(localState)
}

 it ('Testing deleteAxisByID method: ',() => {
 const wrapper = shallow(<AxisList {...baseProps } />);
let id = {test : 'test'}
wrapper.instance().deleteAxisByID(id)
expect(wrapper.instance().state.axis).toHaveProperty('test')

});
```

Here is the main code : file.js

```
    deleteAxisByID = (id) => {
delete this.state.axis[id]
let updateObj = {
  0: {
    pipe: 'chart',
    action: 'transform',
    matchValue: 'axes',
    axes: this.state.axis
  }
}
this.props.addAxisList(updateObj)
```

}

Comment: @estus , i updated my question , i try to run this based on the previous answer and i get the following :      expect(object).toHaveProperty(path)

    Expected the object:
      {}
    To have a nested property:
      "test"

Comment: The question doesn't contain addAxisList. It's unknown what goes wrong. It should contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @estus forgot to copy the previous part

Comment: It still doesn't contain addAxisList. And by the way, you're passing an object as `id` but expect it to be a key. Please, provide all relevant code that is needed to replicate the problem.

Comment: Actually thats all of the code

Comment: I'm quite sure this isn't so. You would have an error that AxisList  is not defined. Because it's not defined in the code you posted. There's no addAxisList in the code you posted. It's unclear why you're calling a function that doesn't exist. Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . The question is unanswerable in its current state. Without MCVE it's considered off-topic and can be closed.